# How to install a newer GCC version (gcc 9.3.0) in Tails?

Tags: tails, linux

I am trying to run a software in Tails that needs to have gcc 9.3.0 installed to launch.

If I do gcc --version I see that the currently installed version is 8.3.0.

How can I install 9.3.0? I'm sure this is easy, but I'm not the best with linux. Thanks!

Comment: Does it really need gcc to run, or can you build it outside of tails with gcc 9.3.0 and then run the compiled binary in tails without gcc? If you really need the latest version of gcc in tails, you probably want to build it from source, but this will take a while.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need a newer version of GCC on Tails in the first place?

You want to be familiar with Debian's package manager, aptitude, because Tails is based on Debian.

Remember that you'll most likely end up doing this every time again because Tails will be back to default the next time you boot (considering that you don't use persistent storage).

If we look at [Debian's website](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/gcc) we see that they didn't provide a binary yet for Debian 9.3.0. This is because Aptitude's packages are extremely stable and usually a little outdated.

So instead we want to go to the official site, download the GCC tarball that we would like (.tar.gz), unpack the tarball with the command `tar xvf <file>.tar.gz` and read the `README.md` file (or something similar) with an explanation on how to build this package.

Because this build can take a pretty long amount of time I highly recommend you to do this on a persistent operating system instead of Tails.